# Get result of tactics application as an expression in Z3

Tags: c++, z3, z3py

Is there anything similar in C++ like Z3py interface's as_expr(). I'm trying to get the result of applying the tactics as a z3 expression, **exp**,  not as type **apply_result**.

For example, in the below code

```
context c;
expr x = c.bool_const("x");
expr y = c.bool_const("y");
expr f = ( (x || y) && (x && y) );
solver s(c);
goal g(c);
g.add( f );
tactic t1(c, "simplify");
apply_result r = t1(g);
std::cout << r << "\n";
```

Also, is there any way to convert the apply_result into z3 expr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the result of a tactic application is a *set* of goals. Most tactics produce only one goal, but some produce more than one. For each of those subgoals, you can use `as_expr()` and then logical-or them together. We can add an `as_expr(...)` to `class apply_result` if that helps. (I'm busy with other stuff at the moment; if you add it yourself, submit a pull request, contributions very welcome!)

Comment: Thanks. Yes i got to understand that, I'll try to do that. Initially i got stuck on this for a few hours, that's why I asked for help :)

Comment: This has now been added (as of https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/commit/cfdde2f4d1d1286d2bfcaad7bf5c7be202b024ad )